# C++ - passing rvalues to function by values

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics

I am just reading "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers and I am testing such a code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int _a) : a(_a)
    {   
        printf("Constructor A %d\n",a);
    }
    A(A&& tmp) noexcept
    {
        printf("MOVE constructor\n");
        a=std::move(tmp.a);
    }
    A(const A & tmp)
    {
        printf("COPY constructor\n");
        a= tmp.a;
    }
 private:
    int a;
 };
std::vector<A> v;
void fun(A temp)
{   
    v.push_back(std::move(temp));
}

void fun2(A&& temp)
{
    v.push_back(std::move(temp));
}

int main()
{
    A x(3);
    fun(x);
    printf("\n");
    fun(A(5));
    printf("\n");
    fun2(A(6));
}
```

Output which I can see is

```
Constructor A 3
COPY constructor
MOVE constructor

Constructor A 5
MOVE constructor
MOVE constructor

Constructor A 6
MOVE constructor
MOVE constructor
MOVE constructor
```

I have doubts about second call of fun. Both move constructors are used during

```
v.push_back(std::move(temp));
```

How it works that no move constructor is used to create param of fun? In first case copy constructor is called so I assume that during second call of fun move constructor should be called. My next question is how it works  that in first call of fun

```
v.push_back(std::move(temp));
```

calls only one move constructor and second call of fun calls 2 move constructor. The same line calls move constructor 3 times during call fun2. Why?

EDIT:
Thanks to comment I added v.reserve(10), and results look much better now

```
Constructor A 3
COPY constructor
MOVE constructor

Constructor A 5
MOVE constructor

Constructor A 6
MOVE constructor
```

Only one question left. How is it that caling

```
fun(A(5))
```

has no effects on any constructor? Is it because of Return Value Optimization?

Comment: Use `v.reserve(10);` before your tests and your result will be different. http://cpp.sh/746u

Comment: IIRC: When you declare a new instance of `A` inside a function call, it is implicitly a move-reference. Since `fun2` expects a move reference, another move constructor gets called there, too.

Comment: The fact that f(A(5)) only call one move constructor is indeed due to return type optimization (spec 12.8), A(5) is constructed in f parmeter temp.